# Getting angular build error while running application through docker

Tags: node.js, angular, docker

I am building the docker image for my angular application but when its building its giving the following error.

```
gyp info using node@14.17.2 | linux | x64
gyp verb command rebuild []
gyp verb command clean []
gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
gyp verb command configure []
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (/app/mean-stack/angular-js/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (/app/mean-stack/angular-js/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (/app/mean-stack/angular-js/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at /app/mean-stack/angular-js/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at /app/mean-stack/angular-js/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at /app/mean-stack/angular-js/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:192:21)
gyp verb `which` failed  python2 Error: not found: python2
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (/app/mean-stack/angular-js/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (/app/mean-stack/angular-js/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (/app/mean-stack/angular-js/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at /app/mean-stack/angular-js/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at /app/mean-stack/angular-js/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at /app/mean-stack/angular-js/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:192:21) {
gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
gyp verb `which` failed }
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (/app/mean-stack/angular-js/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (/app/mean-stack/angular-js/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (/app/mean-stack/angular-js/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at /app/mean-stack/angular-js/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at /app/mean-stack/angular-js/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at /app/mean-stack/angular-js/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:192:21)
gyp verb `which` failed  python Error: not found: python
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (/app/mean-stack/angular-js/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (/app/mean-stack/angular-js/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (/app/mean-stack/angular-js/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at /app/mean-stack/angular-js/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at /app/mean-stack/angular-js/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at /app/mean-stack/angular-js/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:192:21) {
gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
gyp verb `which` failed }
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (/app/mean-stack/angular-js/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:484:19)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (/app/mean-stack/angular-js/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:406:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at F (/app/mean-stack/angular-js/node_modules/which/which.js:68:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at E (/app/mean-stack/angular-js/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
gyp ERR! stack     at /app/mean-stack/angular-js/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
gyp ERR! stack     at /app/mean-stack/angular-js/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
gyp ERR! stack     at /app/mean-stack/angular-js/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:192:21)
gyp ERR! System Linux 5.10.25-linuxkit
gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/app/mean-stack/angular-js/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd /app/mean-stack/angular-js/node_modules/node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v14.17.2
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
Build failed with error code: 1
```

I am using docker ubuntu environment `i.e-FROM ubuntu:20.04`. I am also installing python, node14.X and angular using that dockerfile. Here I need to build the angular env correctly with the dockerfile. I also followed some link but did not get much help. Can somebody help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: The error message seems pretty convinced that python isn't installed. Why do you think it is installed?

Comment: Python is installed because I can show you the logs which is executing before error message . `Step 31/57 : RUN pip3 install lxml
 ---> Running in 17e89181da9c
Collecting lxml
  Downloading lxml-4.6.3-cp38-cp38-manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (6.8 MB)
Installing collected packages: lxml
Successfully installed lxml-4.6.3`